# Machine Learning using database tags to understand what a record is about

Tags: python, machine-learning, k-means

I have a few tables in my database: `projects`, `citations`, `citation_sources`, `tags`. These are the relationships between them.

1. `projects` have multiple `citations` and `citations` belong to `projects`.
2. Each `citation` belong to `citation_sources` and `citation_sources` have multiple `citations`.
3. `citation_sources`have multiple `tags` and a `tag` belongs to `citation_source`

With this structure, I can query all the `tags` that belong to the `citations` in a particular `project`.

I want to use machine learning in python in order to sift through the tags to find out what the project is about. How can I do this? I've heard about K Means but I'm not sure how I can implement it.

Answer (score 0):

The [sklearn module](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cluster.KMeans.html) provides an easy way to implement K-Means. If you know approximately how many 'categories' of tags there are, you can define the number the clusters as the number of 'categories'.